# PHP Two Way encryption with Salt

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to create a two way encryption algorithm for my users passwords.
I need it to be encrypted but without the pre set encrypt pass (what i set)(salt?) the original password cannot be decrypted

Comment: Encrypted data can always be decrypted when using the same key. That’s the [definition of encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption). I guess you rather mean [cryptographic hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use one-way, cryptographic hashing rather than two-way encryption.  Here is a good example of best-practice password storage and validation:

To save it:

$userPasswordInput = $_POST['password'];

$salt = // ideally, generate one randomly and save it to the db, otherwise, use a constant saved to the php file

$password = sha1($userPasswordInput . $salt);

Save $password (and preferably $salt) to the db. When comparing, concatenate the salt and the user input, sha1 it (or whichever encryption), then compare it to the saved (encrypted + salted) password.

Comment: I supose this would work for encryption but. I can't decrypt it and get the password back using the $salt ??

Answer (score 3):

For a two way encryption this is called "key", not "salt". Check out [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) functions.

Comment: I'm going to be using this on multiple servers/sites running PHP. most do not have that extension installed. It'd be hard to update every server/site as well.

Comment: I need something that built into php

Comment: I'm simply looking for a couple of functions i can use to encode and decode a hash, i want a hash to be only decodable if the correct key was used (the one inputted when encoding)

Answer (score 0):

i did it this way:

create a $user + $password

```
$saltedHash = md5($salt.$password);
```

now you have an encrypted password($saltedHash) to save it to the db.

if somebody try to login, you do the same with the inputed password and compare it with the one in the db.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (though very wasteful in terms of storage) is to generate a random string and XOR it to the password. (As someone already pointed out, this is called a key, not a salt.) This is called a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). As the name implies, you cannot reuse the same key for multiple passwords.