# Encrypting POST data in YII

Tags: php, encryption, yii, yii-events

How can I encrypt the post method data from `VIEW` in `YII`? Also is this is a good way to write such a function? It should encrypt POST data in `VIEW` that is sent to - and decrypted in - the controller.

```
'buttons' => array(
            'Edit' =>array(
                //'label' => 'Edit',
                'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("Controller/Action",array("doc_id"=>$data->id))',
            ),
```

When the button is presed, i want to encrypt `"doc_id"` and sent to controller for further action where the encrypted data is again decrypted.
The URL looks something like this..

```
projectName/ControllerName/actionName/a2ewe34r44rf454r
```

But I don't know where to write the function.

Comment: If you're worried about the visibility of URLs between the server and the client, then use SSL - a much easier way to preventing eavesdropping.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption needs to be handled at the transport level.

Configure your web server to use SSL (HTTPS). This will be completely transparent to your PHP so you don't need to modify your code at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is a useless thing.
If you are going to encrypt data with client-side javascript function, note that this function with it's encryption logic will be available to anyone.
So there will be no sense of this encryption.
Everyone who loads the page will be able to view your page source and look how `encryptData()` works.
So I think that **client-side encryption with javascript will not give you any profit**.
A man who is able to get data transmitted by the network will be also able to get your JS function content.

Comment: I want to encrypt the active record content.

Comment: Actually i want to encrypt the data or say id or any other attribute from table entry. That means server side.

Comment: @TNC You want to encrypt form data when it is submitted before sending it to the server?

Comment: Client-side encryption could at least give some headaches for the rev-engineer, but encrypting for transport is a really good thing!

Comment: @godka No headaches if you have the encryptyion algorithm. And in this case we do.

Comment: @godka Why you will use an encryption which can be decrypted by anyone? doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to encrypt id or say mobile no in url, you create your own encryption function, but it will only be anonymous if you encrypt data using variable salts. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3758819/1687983) for salt encryption help.
Thanks.

Comment: In MVC, where the function goes? I have id or something that is taken form the users choice that actually comes from active record, and i want to pass that into controller where the decryption will be done. But am confused in the sense that generally in view no any functions are written.? Any clues??